# Move VC# Project And Maintain Links

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

How do you move a Visual Studio C# project and maintain the linked files?

For example;

- I have a VC# Project that sits in folder: `A/V2013_Project`.
- This VC# Project links to files `A/Image/a.png` this is because we have many other projects that use this file also.
- I want to move my project to `A/Release/V2013_Project`. Ie move the project to a sub-folder.
- I'm not renaming anything in the new project, not changing anything else except for the location of the project.

When I move the project all my links fail (theres more than 50) and most of my references fail. By fail, I mean they no longer point to the file. Within the newly moved VC# project; when I click on a linked file VC# displays an error:

`Cannot find the file A/Image/a.png. It may have been moved or deleted.`

But this file was never moved. Its still in exactly the same place.

How can I move a VC# project and maintain the links and references? Are there any 3rd party addons that can do this?

**Edit:** Using wintermute's advice; the links are indeed relative and not absolute. For example;

```
<Resource Include="..\..\Resources\Other\Images\TOOLBAR_close.png">
  <Link>Resources\Other\Images\TOOLBAR_close.png</Link>
</Resource>
```

Any ideas how I can make links absolute in VC#?

Comment: try to open the project file in an editor, maybe the paths are relative

Comment: @wintermute You're a genius. They are relative. Do you know how to change links to absolute?

Comment: I would not necessarily advise changing links to absolute. This fixes the here-and-now problem, but makes you vulnerable to all sorts of future problems, for example if you move your project from C: to D:, or if the directory structure is different on the build machine from the developer machines.

Comment: One more comment about relative vs. absolute: It is very normal that ALL files in Visual Studio projects are referenced relatively, because this makes it easy to move the project around without breaking links.

Comment: the solution to your prolem is remove project from your existent solution, the make a new one, then add the project to new solution, and add all reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the file is linked. It isn't clear from your question.

Some files are references by the .csproj file. Close Visual Studio down (just to be sure) and open the .csproj file with Notepad or some other text editor. See if the files you're talking about are referenced there. If so, add the text "..\" in front of each file name, indicating they are one directory higher up, relative to the project location.

Some files are referenced in the .resx file(s). In this case Visual Studio should have included the name of the .resx file as part of the error message. This can be fixed using Visual Studio's editor. Double-click on the error message and it should open the .resx file with the file reference that is in error as the selected line. Again, add "..\" in front of the file name.

You say you have 50 references. Hopefully this means you can search-and-replace to add the "..\" text to the relevant file names.

Edit:

You posted an edit to your question, showing this line:

```
<Resource Include="..\..\Resources\Other\Images\TOOLBAR_close.png">
```

If you really want to make this absolute, then just do it.

```
<Resource Include="D:\Merlinia\Trunk-Debug\Add-Ons\Picture Editor\VS2012 projects\PictureEditor\Resources\Other\Images\TOOLBAR_close.png">
```

But as I mention in a comment on your question, make sure this is the best way to fix the problem.